# How to get stats how much lines are committed by a user?

Tags: git, github

Is there any way to get stats how much lines are committed by a certain user (in all repositories he contributes to)?

Comment: Have you checked if there's anything you can use at the [GitHub API](http://developer.github.com/)?

Comment: @Cupcake, this sounds like "implement it all yourself"

Comment: Do you just want to look at them or do you need to access them from code?

Comment: @Steve well, your question is unclear, so I wasn't sure what you were trying to do. Can you please update your question with more details about what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: @Trevor Gowing, just look at them is enough for me

Comment: @SteveKero Have you had a look at the Graphs tab in GitHub?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Github for a particular repository you can go to the graphs tab:

[image: Github graph options]

As you can see there are a number of options there.

To get the number of lines that a user has changed select the Contibutions option.

This will display a card for each user with the number of commits and number of lines added and removed, similarly to the below:

[image: User contributions to a particular repository]

Comment: only on per-repository basis?

Comment: @SteveKero I am afraid so, you can go to your profile page on Github at https://github.com/yourusername and view a summary of your contributions but I do not think that it covers number of lines.